# A question on a matrix identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Sorry for the not very specific title. I was hoping I could get some help with a result I do not understand. The following is from a book I am reading. What I do not understand is how from 9.9.6 one gets to 9.9.7.

[image]

I understand that the rank conditions are fullfilled and thus the matrices are invertible but I fail to see the equivalence between the two formulas. It has been bothering me for some time now so all help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I think we just have $U^{-1}ABV^{-1} = \Gamma_{11}\Gamma'_{21}$, if there are no additional information.

Comment: @SRX $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ are not invertible on their own. That's why you need to the product, to get square matrices of full rank.

Comment: So, we have
$$
AB = U \Gamma_{11}\Gamma_{21}' V \implies\\
U'ABV' = U'U \Gamma_{11}\Gamma_{21}' VV' \implies\\
\Gamma_{11}\Gamma_{21} = 
(U'U)^{-1}U' AB V(VV')^{-1}
$$
But I'm with you here; I don't see how we're supposed to conclude that
$$
(U'U)^{-1}U' AB V(VV')^{-1}= AB
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Indeed, thank you. For completeness, the extract comes from Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, 7th edition by Hogg, Craig and McKean pages 516-517.

Comment: In (9.9.6) A and B are uppercase English letters, while in (9.9.7) A and B are uppercase Greek letters? :)